# What are allowed_methods in shipping method magento

Tags: magento-1.6, shipping-methods

I am very new in magento. I am creating a shipping module. I want to know what is the meaning of **allowed_methods** shipping method.

Can I use my own allowed_methods in shipping methods.

Answer (score 1):

Shipping Carrier can offer several shipping methods: ground, air, next day, etc.
Depending on the customer address some of them are not allowed.

Please see `app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php`